# How can we achieve textAlign="center" within box in case of multiline text using ffmpeg drawtext?

Tags: ffmpeg

When working with drawtext in ffmpeg, it allows to enable box to show behind the text, and also allows to assign some background color to it.

But when it comes to multiline text, let's say there are three lines as shown in picture as current result:

[image: current results]

It never align text to center. But I want results like shown below:

[image: Required Output]

This time am using following ffmpeg command to draw text:

`-vf "drawtext=text='${text}': x=((w*${x})/${DIMENSIONS.width}): y=((h*${y})/${DIMENSIONS.height}):fontsize=36:fontcolor=yellow@0.9: box=1: boxcolor=black@0.6:boxborderw=20" -c:a copy`

Comment: Use 1 drawtext filter for each line and use drawbox to make the box. Or use ASS subtitles with the [subtitles filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles) (optionally with [drawbox filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#drawbox) for the box or by using ASS [drawing tags](https://aegi.vmoe.info/docs/3.0/ASS_Tags/)).

Comment: Thanks, @llogan I got the trick, I'll try that.